# How to attach PDF to email using PHP

Tags: php, forms, pdf, email-attachments

> This is php code and its working, all the form content successfully send to mail id, but i want to attach PDF file also to email using php this function.
>   But how i can, i don't know.

I would like to add a specified PDF file as a file attachment to the email. How would I do that?

```
<?php
$name  = $_REQUEST["name"];
$phone = $_REQUEST["phone"];
$email = $_REQUEST["email"];
$address = $_REQUEST["address"];
$message = $_REQUEST["message"];
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
$todayis = date("y-m-d H:i:s", time());
$subject = "PVC Order From Website ";
$to      = "iamrightful@gmail.com";
$msg .= "<table width='600' border='0' align='center' cellpadding='0' ellspacing='0' style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
font-size:13pt; border:1px solid #0f3f6a;'>";
$msg .= "<tr>";
$msg .= "<td width='16' height='25' bgcolor='#f9cf7b'>&nbsp;</td>";
$msg .= "<td width='96' bgcolor='#f9cf7b'>Name</td>";
$msg .= "<td width='10' height='25' bgcolor='#f9cf7b'><strong>:</strong></td>";
$msg .= "<td height='25' bgcolor='#f9cf7b'>$name</td>";
$msg .= "</tr>";
$msg .= "<tr>";
$msg .= "<td height='25' bgcolor='#f9cf7b'>&nbsp;</td>";
$msg .= "<td height='25' bgcolor='#f9cf7b'>Mobile </td>";
$msg .= "<td height='25' bgcolor='#f9cf7b'><strong>:</strong></td>";
$msg .= "<td height='25' bgcolor='#f9cf7b'>$phone</td>";
$msg .= "</tr>";
$msg .= "<tr>";
$msg .= "<tr>";
$msg .= "<td height='25' bgcolor='#f9cf7b'>&nbsp;</td>";
$msg .= "<td height='25' bgcolor='#f9cf7b'>Email Id </td>";
$msg .= "<td height='25' bgcolor='#f9cf7b'><strong>:</strong></td>";
$msg .= "<td height='25' bgcolor='#f9cf7b'>$email</td>";
$msg .= "</tr>";
$msg .= "<tr>";
$msg .= "<td height='25'>&nbsp;</td>";
$msg .= "<td height='25'>Address</td>";
$msg .= "<td height='25'><strong>:</strong></td>";
$msg .= "<td height='25'>$address</td>";
$msg .= "</tr>";
$msg .= "<tr>";
$msg .= "<td height='25'>&nbsp;</td>";
$msg .= "<td height='25'>Discription</td>";
$msg .= "<td height='25'><strong>:</strong></td>";
$msg .= "<td height='25'>$message</td>";
$msg .= "</tr>";
$msg .= "</table>";
$headers = "From: $c_name < $c_email >.";
$headers = "Bcc: admin < $Bcc >.";
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
header("Location:thankyou.html");
```

Comment: Do yourself a favour and use an existing library like PHPMailer. Will take all the pain out of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you will pass three values to the mail() function plus some headers. In the example below I skip the value for the message value, because the message is defined as a MIME part together with the attachment.

```
function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message) {
 $file = $path.$filename;
 $file_size = filesize($file);
 $handle = fopen($file, "r");
 $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
 fclose($handle);
 $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
 $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
 $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
 $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
 $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
 $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
 $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
 $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
 $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
 $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
 $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
 $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
 $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
 $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
 $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
 $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
 $header .= "--".$uid."--";
 if (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)) {
 echo "mail send ... OK"; // or use booleans here
 } else {
 echo "mail send ... ERROR!";
 }
}
```

Below is an example on how I use this function to send an email message with one attached .zip file:

```
$my_file = "somefile.zip";
$my_path = "/your_path/to_the_attachment/";
$my_name = "Olaf Lederer";
$my_mail = "my@mail.com";
$my_replyto = "my_reply_to@mail.net";
$my_subject = "This is a mail with attachment.";
$my_message = "Hallo,rndo you like this script? I hope it will help.rnrngr. Olaf";
mail_attachment($my_file, $my_path, "recipient@mail.org", $my_mail, $my_name, $my_replyto, $my_subject, $my_message);
```

Comment: hi, have u done, or getting any error, you also use php mailer class to send mail using SMTP with your server host, username and password. SMTP also allow to send mail from localhost. so if u want SMTP example reply me i will provide u his details also

Comment: in below example you need to pass
//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;  //Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP();  //Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  //Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  //Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';  //SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret'; //SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';   //Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted$mail->Port = 587; 
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient

Comment: create one email in your cpanel and user his smtp detail or just pass GMAIL or any other email smtp details here to send mail from localhost in your domain it possible gmail or other client details is not work for security reason, for that you must pass your domain email it ex. (abc@example.com) where example.com is you own domain

Comment: update you question and add latest code so i will check it and reply u.

Comment: Give me ur number or email id, 
 i will send error on whatapp to u

Comment: Dear Mahipal Patel sir, 
I sent you mail please check your mail id.

Answer (score 1):

Download the PHPMailer library from the link given below:

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

and then use this code

```
require_once('../PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->From      = '';
$mail->FromName  = '';
$mail->Subject   = '';
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$name." "."\r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$email." "."\r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Contact No.: ".$cno." "."\r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Message: ".$message." "."\r\n";
$mail->Body      = $MESSAGE_BODY;
$mail->AddAddress( '' );

$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
                 $_FILES['file']['name']);

if ($mail->Send())
{   
    echo "Mail Sent";
}
else
{
    echo "Could not send mail";
}
```

It will work fine.

Comment: i used but it not working its show "Could not send mail"

Comment: <?php
 require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->From      = '';
$mail->FromName  = '';
$mail->Subject   = '';
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$username." "."\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Contact No.: ".$contact." "."\r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Message: ".$message." "."\r\n";
$mail->Body      = $MESSAGE_BODY;
$mail->AddAddress( '' );

$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
                 $_FILES['file']['username']);

if ($mail->Send())
{   
    echo "Mail Sent";
}
else
{
    echo "Could not send mail";
}
?>

Comment: yes bro but it still not working. ;(
Please send me full code of php ..

Comment: i have already sent you the full code.....try to send the email firstly without attachment and one more thing is your application is online or offline?

Comment: just upload the error image file at onionfiles.com and give me the link.

Comment: OK sir.
php file link
https://onionfiles.com/file/iH84vCPr

HTML PAGE link
https://onionfiles.com/file/I1kGZv7E

Please check it.

Comment: if you did'nt get it share your email id.
i will mail you all file.

Comment: i sent you mail
Please check your email id.

Comment: In $mail->From you have to write from which mail you want to send email and in $mail->FromName write the company name or website name and in $mail->AddAddress( '' ) write the email to which the email is to be sent and comment the add attachment code and then try..

Comment: and make sure that class.phpmailer.php file is placed under phpmailer directory and phpmailer directory should be located in the same location where your html file is placed

Comment: OK sir
Thank you so much.
phpmailer directory & html file placed same location.

Comment: no still its shows error.
Bro can you mail me proper/full code of PHP.
i want to attached PDF file and send it into Gmail.

Comment: i have sent you email.

Comment: Thank you bro 
But now its working
Thank you once again bro.
bs wahi problem tha jo apne bataya tha 
Thank you so much. 
Have a great day ;)